# how to translate this xpath into css selector

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Basically, the question is how to convert and and not operators correctly in the given xpath:

```
"//div[contains(@class, 'cpthead') or contains(@class, 'cptbulkhead') and (not(contains(@class, 'overloaded') or contains(@class, 'loaded')))]"
```

the answer is :

```
 .cpthead:not(.overloaded):not(.loaded),cptbulkhead:not(.overloaded):not(.loaded)
```

Comment: Please do not edit the question with the answer. You have already _accepted_ an answer correctly, as described in the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), so if you have more to add then please comment (if you can) on that answer, or answer and accept the question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate multiple class selectors in CSS to translate your XPath `and`, and then use pseudo-class `:not()` to translate XPath `not()`, something like this :

```
div.cpthead.cptbulkhead.loaded:not(.overloaded)
```

Comment: And what about the "or"?

Answer (score 1):

For the *or* you can use a comma, like this:

```
div.cpthead.cptbulkhead.loaded:not(.overloaded),
div.cpthead.cpthead.loaded:not(.overloaded)
```

*PS: It's a reply of har07's answer but I can't post comments...*